# Calling a function with a paramater in click causes error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a computed Vue function that has a parameter. Every time I try to bind it to the click, I receive and error `Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: searchHashtag is not a function"`

Here's the HTML:

```
<el-button @click="searchHashtag('#acc')">Test</el-button>
```

And here's the logic:

```
data () {
     messages: []
},

mounted () {
     api.fetchMessages( this.projectId, ( data ) => {
          this.messages = data.messages;
},

computed: {
     searchHashtag (searchBy) {
          if (_.contains(this.messages, searchBy))
               this.$message('This is a message.');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a method, not a computed property.

```
methods: {
     searchHashtag (searchBy) {
          if (_.contains(this.messages, searchBy))
               this.$message('This is a message.');
     }
}
```

Computed properties cannot be called like a function. They act like properties of the Vue and do not take arguments. When you need a function that accepts arguments, always use a method.